# CSS Bootstrap list below table

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular 8 with Bootstrap and Angular Mats.

I have the following:

```
<header>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search by Title, Keyword, or File Type.." name="search" autofocus [(ngModel)]="filterBar">      
    </nav>
    <table mat-table class="table">
      <thead>
          <th mat-header-cell>
              <p>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select placeholder="Filter By" [(value)]="filterBy">
                      <mat-option value="">All Media</mat-option>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let media of medias" value="{{media.type}}">{{media.type}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </p>
          </th>
          <th mat-header-cell>
              <p>
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select placeholder="Sort By" [(value)]="sortBy">
                        <mat-option value="date">Date Uploaded</mat-option>
                        <mat-option value="name">Alphabetical</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </p>
          </th>
          <th mat-header-cell>
                <p>
                  <button mat-button (click)="clearclick($event)">Clear</button>
                </p>
          </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let media of medias | orderBy: sortBy : false | filter:filterBar | filter:filterBy | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
          <td>{{media.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <pagination-controls class="float-right" (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This displays a table and in the table header there are some drop-downs. When I select a dropdown, the `options` display beneath the table. As you can see the filter options (All Media, Videos, Interactive Vids, Audio, Images) are displayed beneath the table.

[image]

**Question:**

How do I change it to display the dropdown options under the Filter By header over the table?

Comment: Can you recreate this in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: Hi Mendy, I have been trying to add it to here, but it doesn't get past the loading stage. Will continue to try fix it.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fga4wi

Comment: Try changing the `my-app` in index.html with `app-root`